# Google Search Console- wrong counter

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I've created two sitemaps. One sitemap has over 400.000 links and I use a sitemap index for that. The Search Console gives me the status that the links are submitted and indexed but I don't see any count. I can't find them on google either.

The other sitemap is without an index and works as expected.

How can I solve this problem?